# Test satisfiability with respect to a fixed partial model

Tags: models, z3

Assume that I have asserted some formula *P* and, after checking satisfiability, obtained from Z3 a *partial* model for it, let's call it *M*.

Now, would it be possible to test whether another formula *Q* can be satisfied by extending, if necessary, the current model *M*. That is, I want to check whether the formula *P and Q* is satisfiable but fixing the values that have been assigned by the current partial model.

Alternatively, is it possible to ask Z3 to “complete” a specific partial model? (That is, I still want to obtain partial models; but, in a few cases, I would like to be able to extend a partial model so that I can then evaluate some arbitrary formula *Q* which might contain constants/functions not assigned by the current model)

Answer (score 2):

Would it work in your situation to check *P*, extract the partial model *M*, construct a formula *N* that is just the conjunction of equalities assigned in *M*, then check *N and Q*?  This should be directly implementable using the API, but probably less so with a text interface.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that, but I was hopping for some more efficient way to achieve this directly within Z3 (the model *is* already in there). Anyway, if there is no other solution at the moment, I will check and compare between implementing this "model-formula" construction, or simply asking for complete models from the beginning. Btw, intuitively, would there be a large efficiency loss if I were to switch from partial to complete models?